# Display Result in Same Page Using python flask

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I am using python flask for sending form data into another HTML template. I need to show the result in same page where HTML input form exists. Currently response is being forwarded to next page.

I tried to run via JQuery but still unable to get the result.

app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def student():
   return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/result',methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def result():
   if request.method == 'POST':
      result = request.form
      return render_template("result.html",result = result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(debug = True)
```

index.html

```
<html>
   <body>
      <form action = "http://localhost:5000/result" method = "POST">
         <p>Name <input type = "text" name = "Name" /></p>
         <p>Physics <input type = "text" name = "Physics" /></p>
         <p>Chemistry <input type = "text" name = "chemistry" /></p>
         <p>Maths <input type ="text" name = "Mathematics" /></p>
         <p><input type = "submit" value = "submit" /></p>
      </form>
   <div>
   </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Result.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
   <body>
      <table border = 1>
         {% for key, value in result.items() %}
            <tr>
               <th> {{ key }} </th>
               <td> {{ value }} </td>
            </tr>
         {% endfor %}
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

Now the result is displayed at result.html, i need that to be displayed on index.html. Please suggest, how to make this happen.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an older question, but for anyone else that's possibly interested. All you have to do is change

```
return render_template("result.html",result = result)
```

to

```
return render_template("index.html",result = result)
```

or to whatever other page you may want to return to. Render_template just returns whatever you ask it to, if you want to return just the data, or something else you can just say

```
return (data)
```

or whatever your data is called.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your problem correctly, I can see multiple ways:

**1)**
You can have your `result.html` included in your `index.html`.
Then you just pass your result data into `render_template` function.
*read more about templates [here](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#include)*

it will look something like this:

```
{% include 'result.html' %}
```

in `index.html`
and `result.html` will look like:

```html
<div id="result_div">
  some code
</div>
```

**2)**
You can use AJAX to post form data, generate html in flask, pass it as AJAX result and update your page with it via javascript.

```js
$.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: '/result',
                        data: JSON.stringify({
                            'data' : data,
                        }),
                        contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
                        success: function(response){
                            // fill with html
                            $('#result_div').html(response.result);

                        },
                        error: function(error) {
                            // console.log(error);
                        }
                    });
```

of course you will have to update your flask code on `/results` too.

In both cases, you want to have one page (which can consist of multiple html files).